# Ubuntu sometimes logs me in WITHOUT asking for password!

Tags: login, 17.10, security

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and have noticed a very dangerous situation which I am unable to prevent. It happens when I send a machine to sleep and wake it up the next day.

Namely, from time to time (let's say once in 30 or 50 resumes), when I wake it from sleep, logs me into account WITHOUT asking for a password.

It seems like something has crashed silently and login screen has been skipped. I usually end up on my desktop with frozen screen for a few seconds, and then all refreshes and I can use the system normally.

When I first installed 17.10, it started happening more often. Then I thought that a machine does not lock the system when I sleep the machine. So I now manually first lock the machine (`Win` + `L`) and then send the system to sleep.

But from time time, I still end up on the desktop without having to enter my password.

Is there a patch for this security flaw?

Comment: Have you reported a bug?

Comment: My guess is that it's `gnome-shell` which crashes and restarts due to low memory.

Comment: @pomsky Loe memory? This machine is i7 with 16GB RAM.

Comment: @muru No, I did not. Maybe someone knows how to fix it as being a reported bug already.

Comment: You should. If it was reported, it will be marked as a duplicate and no harm done. If it wasn't, you're risking devs not being aware of it.

Comment: @ubuntico I don't see that info mentioned anywhere in the question. Also as I said, it's just a guess.